# Entrusted stuff or stuff to take care of

Tags: word-request

For the thing that is given to someone for a while to take care of and then this will be taken back, what word is used by natives? Do you use 'entrusted stuff'? The example could be some books such as. I'm going somewhere and can't take these with me. I ask my friend to keep these safe and return them to me when I'm back. Without mentioning the name of the thing my friend is taking care of, can I say:

---

He's got some entrusted stuff.

---

What do natives get by the phrase 'entrusted stuff'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be understandable in context, but far better would be to use a more specific verb for what he is doing:

> He's taking care of some stuff (for me).
>
> He's looking after some of my stuff.

Or use a specific word for what you have done:

> I've entrusted him with some of my belongings, until I get back.

If you need to use a modifier+noun, then use a relative clause:

> (my) stuff that he is looking after (for me)
>   stuff that I have entrusted to him.

The examples using the word "entrusted" are more formal in style.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "entrust:

> [**entrust**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entrust) (verb) = to give someone a thing or a duty for which they are responsible:
>
> - He didn't look like the sort of man you should entrust your luggage to.
> - Two senior officials have been entrusted with organizing the auction.

---

Or you can use: "to give for safe-keeping".

> I **gave** the books to my friend, **for safe-keeping**.